# Table row is higher than specified with CSS (only iPhone)

Tags: javascript, html, ios, css, html-table

My goal is to **fix the first column of a table** and make the rest of the table scrollable horizontal.

See jsfiddle for reference: https://jsfiddle.net/e1thx7sj/4/ *(scrolling omitted)*

My main steps to reach this aim are:

1. Create **a copy** of the existing table (jquery clone)
2. **Insert** this copy next to the existing table
3. From the copy, remove all table cells **except of the first one in each row**.
4. Lay this single column copy with z-index and absolute positioning **over the first column of the main table**.

This is the code:

```
var $table = $('.table');
// clone the table and insert it with an additional class
var $fixedColumn = $table.clone().insertBefore($table).addClass('fixed-column');
// remove all cells except of the first column cells
$fixedColumn.find('thead tr:first-child th:not(:first-child)').remove();
$fixedColumn.find('thead tr:not(:first-child) th').remove();
$fixedColumn.find('td:not(:first-child)').remove();
```

So far so good. But the heights of the rows in the "fixed column" don't fit to the row heights of the main table. It looks like this:

[image]

So I wrote a JS funtion (setRowHeightsEqualToBaseTable in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e1thx7sj/4/)) to adpat the row heights.

```
function setRowHeightsEqualToBaseTable() {
   $fixedColumn.find('tr').each(function(i, elem) {
      var $row = $(this);
      var $fixedColumn = $row.parents('table');
      var $baseTable = $fixedColumn.siblings('table:not(.fixed-column)');
      var cellHeight = $baseTable.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')'[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
      $row.outerHeight(cellHeight);
   });
}
```

This works perfectly. 
But **not on iPhone Chrome / iPhone Safari.**

Even if the css height attribute is set correctly (36px), the browser calculates another value for the height (56px).

I guess it has something to do with the line-height as this (20px) is the difference between the heights. But I can't figure out why there is this difference.

Comment: Try setting the css rule `-webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%;` on your table cells.

Comment: Unfortunately, that has no desired effect on the cell height...

Comment: if you use :first-of-type instead of :first-child does it make a difference?  https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/

Comment: I would use visibility (cssc), instead remove() ) and not reset the display, so both table (original and clone) are similar and behave the same : https://jsfiddle.net/e1thx7sj/5/

Comment: ... any feed back about my proposal ? ... this what it could do https://jsfiddle.net/e1thx7sj/7/

Comment: @GCyrillus Yes thank you very much! A very valuable advice! I use the visibility: hidden way instead of removing the cells and: It works :)

Comment: @GCyrillus: would you like to post it as answer?

Comment: Here you go, hope it worked fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead `remove()` to hide your cells, you should use `css()` (`visibility` or `opacity`) , so not only structure but column's & row's size remains identical.

some `z-index` have to be set and reset to keep content of your cells reacting to mouse events.

For a better interaction with the style, it might also be wised to set that clone one level higher (to deal with `overflow:hidden` and then `overflow:scroll`).

example

```js
// get the table
var $table = $('.table');
// clone the table and insert it with an additional class
var $fixedColumn = $table.clone().insertBefore($table).addClass('fixed-column');
// remove all cells except of the first column cells
$fixedColumn.find('thead tr:first-child th:not(:first-child)').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$fixedColumn.find('thead tr:not(:first-child) th').css('visibility', 'hidden');
$fixedColumn.find('td:not(:first-child)').css('visibility', 'hidden');


setRowHeightsEqualToBaseTable();

/**
 * Each tr in the fixed column should have the same height as the underlying table row.
 */
function setRowHeightsEqualToBaseTable() {
  $fixedColumn.find('tr').each(function(i, elem) {
    var $row = $(this);
    var $fixedColumn = $row.parents('table');
    var $baseTable = $fixedColumn.siblings('table:not(.fixed-column)');
    var cellHeight = $baseTable.find('tr:eq(' + i + ')')[0].getBoundingClientRect().height;
    $row.outerHeight(cellHeight);
  });
}

/**
 * On resize of the window the heights of table row may change - update view
 */
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  setRowHeightsEqualToBaseTable();
});
```

```css
.table-wrapper {
  width:100%;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}
.table-parent {
  width:100%;
  overflow:auto;
}
.fixed-column {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  }

.fixed-column th, .fixed-column td {
  background-color: white;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
}

.table {
    border: none;
    border-collapse: separate;
    display: table;
    border-spacing: 0;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    max-width: 150%;
    width: 150%;
    background-color: transparent;
}

.table > thead > tr > th.first-col {
  width: 130px !important;
  min-width: 130px !important;
  max-width: 130px !important;
}

.table tbody tr td {
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-top: 1px solid gray;
}
.table tbody tr td:first-child {
  border-left: none;
}
.table-parent > .table tr :first-child ~ *,
.table-wrapper .fixed-column tr :first-child {
  background:white;
  position:relative;
  z-index:2
}
.table-wrapper .fixed-column tr :first-child {
  z-index:3
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="table-wrapper">
  <div class="table-parent">
    <table class="table">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th rowspan="2" class="first-col">Device Name,<br/>Product Brand</th>
          <th rowspan="2">Lorem ipsum,<br/>Lorem ipsum</th>
          <th rowspan="2" style="width: 100px;">Lorem ipsum</th>
          <th colspan="4">Lorem ipsum</th>
          <th rowspan="2" style="width: 70px;">Lorem ipsum</th>
          <th rowspan="2" style="width: 40px;">Lorem ipsum</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th style="width: 65px;">V</th>
          <th style="width: 65px;">V</th>
          <th style="width: 65px;">V</th>
          <th style="width: 65px;">V</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#">A link</a></td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#">A link</a></td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#">A link</a></td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td><a href="#">A link</a></td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
          <td>Lorem ipsum</td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/e1thx7sj/7/